# voltage regulators and capacitors

Tags: voltage, capacitor, voltage-regulator

So I'm new to electronics and was looking at some Eagle schematics when I came across the following voltage regulator schematic:

[image]

My question is: would it be possible to change the regulator to another one (with the same caps), for example [this one](http://www.digikey.com/scripts/dksearch/dksus.dll?FV=fff40027,fff80182&vendor=0&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ptm=0&fid=0&quantity=0&PV-1=150&PV48=108)

Comment: Download the two data data sheets and compare them. They will have details of the capacitors that are required.

Comment: @Leon It's really hard for an electronics beginner to compare two components based on their datasheets. What are the relevant parameters?

Comment: The input and output capacitors are usually specified in regulator data sheets.

Comment: No way we can help you if you don't specify the input voltage (VI). The output voltage (VO) is apparently 3V3 as the circuit diagram is drawn the other way around than most EE's prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, the answer is "it depends", in this case on the (power) requirements of the circuit. It's quite likely that you'll be able to find a different regulator that will work with the same set of capacitors (the precise values are often not that crucial). However, the one you linked to certainly won't work as it is a -5V regulator, whereas the regulator in the schematic is a +3.3V one.

Comment: ahh right, i meant to pick a +5V one. more like [this one](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/MCP1702T-5002E%2FCB/MCP1702T-5002E%2FCBTR-ND/1098473). 

but why the 2 caps at the left side? Is the 10uF not enough?

Comment: Voltage regulators with the wrong capacitors make quite good radio transmitters. 10uf is self-resonant at a relatively low frequency, where the regulator probably still has gain. The 0.1uf is still a good capacitor where the larger one has become inductive.